Parse JSON to get only parent name, and not its object
I have looked at JSON parsing to get parent name which shows how to get a single parent name (without going into its child object).
But how would I get sibling parents, such that i need an array of someParentName, someParentName3 ?
const obj = { 
 "someParentName":{
   "somechild":{
     "value1":"test"
   }
 },
  "someParentName3":{
   "somechild":{
     "value1":"test3"
   }
 }
}

My actual data is as follows, where what i need is the names of the participants: contact5 and contact6.
{
   "id":"1733153805736",
   "participants":{
      "contact5":{
         "access":"ReadWrite",
         "notify":true,
         "isUnread":true,
         "joinedAt":1733153806310
      },
      "contact6":{
         "access":"ReadWrite",
         "notify":true,
         "isUnread":true,
         "joinedAt":1733153806314
      }
   },
   "custom":{
      
   },
   "subject":"more cats",
   "createdAt":1733153806307,
   "topicId":null,
   "photoUrl":null,
   "welcomeMessages":[
      "Regarding: Let's continue discussing this here"
   ],
   "lastMessage":{
      "id":"msg_4t2rWzoYH2YgsTk6bXqvWn",
      "type":"UserMessage",
      "origin":"rest",
      "location":null,
      "text":"Let's continue discussing this here",
      "content":[
         {
            "type":"text",
            "children":[
               "Let's continue discussing this here"
            ]
         }
      ],
      "attachment":null,
      "custom":{
         "forwardedFrom":"1733236324331"
      }
   }
}


Object.keys(obj.participants)?

@deceze -Thank you
